# Browser-based front-end to database-like server app

Tags: io, client-server

I am looking to develop a browser-based front-end/client to what is essentially a database-like back-end/server.

The server application will need to access some local hardware I/O and will be logging events to a database (or even a fixed format text file).

The front-end needs to display real-time status of the remote I/O, as well as be able to browse the event log by date.  This means that the server will likely need to be able to push to the client as events happen or status changes.

My background is in embedded/firmware, assembly, C/C++, and I have done a fair bit of work with Windows/MFC clients providing UI to devices via TCP/IP, UDP, and serial connections, but I don't have any web based experience.

The number of choices for web development these days is overwhelming, so I am really looking for somebody with experience to point me in the right direction for which technologies/platforms to consider researching.  (ie. AJAX, ASP.NET, NODE.JS, Javascript, PHP...)

I suspect providing the information to the front-end will be the easier part, and that the back-end will require two parts (one app/service to interface with the hardware and create a database/file that the other part can access and serve to the client).

What tools/platforms/technologies would you recommend to tackle this, and why?

Any advice is appreciated.  (Links to references/tutorials also appreciated).

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Was looking for recommendations as to how to approache the problem.  Added an explicit question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [ext.js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) framework. This is a client-side framework that is server agnostic that can greatly speed up development. Being a client framework it is based on JavaScript an can talk via AJAX with JSON/XML to server-side systems. It offers a very rich and professional experience and wirth the $595 price tag.

You build most of your application client-side and it can works with almost any back-end. The engine is fast enough to display real-time data and has a strong developer community.